# Wifi on Acer Aspire VN7-792G on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, acer

Hallo Ubuntu community forum,
I can't pride a broad experience with Ubuntu but at least I can use it to do my PhD work by working with different applications. I have had many Laptop devices before and I didn't have a problem with the WLAN card. The driver(s) was installed automatically. But there seems to be a problem with Wifi on the Acer Aspire VN7-792G Laptop device. Can someone help us figure a solution to this? Most of the help pages on the internet are falling short of my expectation. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the bug relatet with your problem:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1520343

Here is a solution for the wirless problems

```
sudo mkdir -p /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/

sudo rm /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/* 2> /dev/null

sudo wget -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin https://github.com/FireWalkerX/ath10k-firmware/blob/7e56cbb94182a2fdab110cf5bfeded8fd1d44d30/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin?raw=true

sudo wget -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin https://github.com/FireWalkerX/ath10k-firmware/blob/7e56cbb94182a2fdab110cf5bfeded8fd1d44d30/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin_WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1?raw=true

sudo chmod +x /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/*
```